# In Terraform aws_ecs_task_definition how do I define bind mount in the volume section

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In terraform how do is set the volume type when defining ecs taskdefinition volume. Is there a way to define volume type "Bind Mount" in terrafrom. The documentation does not seems to provide any details

[aws_ecs_task_definition](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition#volume-block-arguments)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just create is as follows:

```
  volume {
    name      = "my-bind-volume"
  }
```

If you want specific path you can use:

```
  volume {
    name      = "my-bind-volume"
    host_path = "/ecs/service-storage"
  }
```